# Is using voice effects on TikTok haram

Tags: halal-haram, sin, doubts

Is using voice effect like vibrator on TikTok permissible or haram

Comment: You’re going to have to tell us what the “vibrator” effect is on TikTok

Comment: It’s like a wiggle funny voice effect

Comment: I mean, as long as it doesn’t involve anything haram like music, swearing, etc. or related to the themes of haram dancing, I don’t see an issue with it. Though some may find it displeasing since you’re altering the voice that Allah bestowed, in a mocking sense.